# Card game with 36 cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a card game with 36 cards, 9 hearts and 27 different cards. I split the 36 cards into 4 equal decks. In the first deck I have one heart, in the 2nd deck I have 2 hearts, in the 3rd I have three hearts and in the 4th also three hearts.

You choose deck 1 with probability $P(X=1)=\frac{2}{5}$, deck 2 with $P(X=2)=\frac{1}{5}=P(X=3)=P(X=4)$. Now I want to calculate different things (may you can help me with that) .

(a) What is the probability to draw a heart? My attempt $P(X=Heart)=\frac{2}{5}*\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{5}*\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{5}*\frac{3}{9}+\frac{1}{5}*\frac{3}{9}$

(b) Imagine you already have a heart card. What is the probability you chose the first deck (so the heart is from the 1st deck)? Intuitively I would say $\frac{1}{4}$

(c) Let $K\in\{1,2,3,...\}$ be the first time you draw a heart. What is the disitribution and the expectation of $K$? For this I need $P(K=i)$ but I do not know how to evaluate it.

(d) You play $18$ rounds. Let $L$ be the number of hearts you have drawn. Again what is $P(L=i)?$

Comment: For (a) you want $\frac{1}{9}$, $\frac{2}{9}$, $\frac{3}{9}$, $\frac{3}{9}$ instead if $\frac{1}{8}$, $\frac{2}{7}$, $\dots$.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks. I'will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part (a) is correct.

For part (b), it is asking for:
$$ \begin{align*}
P(\text{from deck 1} \mid \text{chose heart})&=\dfrac{P(\text{chose heart from deck 1})}{P(\text{chose heart})}\\
&=\dfrac{\frac{2}{5}*\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{2}{5}*\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{5}*\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{5}*\frac{3}{9}+\frac{1}{5}*\frac{3}{9}}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{2+2+3+3} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{5}
\end{align*}$$

For parts (c) and (d), it depends on whether you are drawing cards **with** or **without** replacement. In either case, to find $P(K=i)$, you must calculate the probability that your first $i-1$ cards are all not hearts but your $i$th card is a heart.

---

**EDIT:** Alright, let's assume it's with replacement. Then by part (a), we have:
$$
P(K=i)=[P(\text{chose non-heart})]^{i-1} \cdot P(\text{chose heart}) = \left(\dfrac{7}{9}\right)^{i-1}\left(\dfrac{2}{9}\right)
$$
Thus, the expectation is:
$$
E(K)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i \cdot P(K=i)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[i\left(\dfrac{7}{9}\right)^{i-1}\left(\dfrac{2}{9}\right) \right] = \dfrac{9}{2}
$$

As for part (d), observe that $L\sim Binomial(18,2/9)$. The pdf of this random variable is given by:
$$
P(L=i)=\binom{18}{i}(2/9)^i(7/9)^{18-i}
$$
where $L \in \{0,1,...,18\}$.

Comment: Thanks, if we consider it with replacement, what do you get for $P(K=i)$?

Comment: I think it is $(i-1)\frac{7}{9}i\frac{2}{9}$ because $\frac{7}{9}$ is the probability not getting a heart

Comment: @Voyage I've updated my solution, taking into account the new information.

Comment: $K$ can be any value between $1$ and $36$, correct? Or betwwen 1 and infnity?

Comment: As you state, we have $K \in \{1,2,3,...\}$, so it can be arbitrarily large.